# Including Forms, Action Problem

Tags: php, forms

Say Im reading a thread or browsing threads

at `read.php?tid=1` or `category.php?cid=1` respectively

And my form `post_form.php` which is `included();` uses this value for a few isset functions to make sure there is a subject and body, however the form action is pointing to post.php which handles the form, so if no body and subject is submitted, the `?tid or ?cid` is lost and the form brings you to posts.php

What would be the best way to pass the post form the parent `tid?` or `cid?` value?

Comment: Just making sure, but you do know you can supply a full URL with a query string to the action of a form right ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `type="hidden"` INPUT elements to include values you don't want the user to see/manipulate.

```
<form ... >
 <input type="hidden" name="tid" value="00001"/>
 <input type="hidden" name="cid" value="abc-009"/>
...
</form>
```

Also, if you need to load the CID/TID data into form fields, you can try the following (with hidden fields instead, I used text fields so you could see it working):

```
CID: <input type="text" id="cid" name="cid" value=""/><br/>
TID: <input type="text" id="tid" name="tid" value=""/>

function getString() {
    // You want to use the first one that I commented out, and remove the other.
    //var url = unescape(window.document.location);
    var url = "http://www.example.com/?tid=0011&cid=mainpromo2";
    var get = {};

    if (url.indexOf('?') > -1) {
        _get = url.substr(url.indexOf('?')+1);
        _get = _get.split("&");
        for (var i = 0; i < _get.length; i++) {
            pairs = _get[i].split('=');
            key = pairs[0];
            value = pairs[1];
            get[key] = value;
        }
    }

    return get;
}

getvars = getString();

document.getElementById('cid').value = getvars.cid;
document.getElementById('tid').value = getvars.tid;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/Vuenp/1/

(Note the above needs to run AFTER the form is parsed.)

Of course, this would be easier if you used jQuery.

Comment: Im getting closer, my tid action is working but not my cid. You definately pointed me in the right direction though thanks.

Comment: No problem. Make sure and upvote the answer and hit the checkmark next to it to mark it as answered. :)

Comment: No worries; I forgot about that. :)

Comment: It took me an hour to find out that the cid wasn't working because I wrote $POST_['cid'] -_- dreamweaver doesn't pick this up I guess one more question my guru

 $tid = FALSE;
  echo "Thread POST.PHP ID = $tid";
 if (isset($_POST['tid']) && is_numeric($_POST['tid']) ) {
  $tid = (int) $_POST['tid'];

  if ($tid <= 0) { 
   $tid = FALSE;
  }
  echo "Thread POST.PHP ID = $tid";
  
 }

I believe the `$tid = FALSE;` is called a flag variable but I have no idea what this does, I echoed it out twice to try and figure it out. I dont understand how I can set a variable to false while it returns a valu

Comment: PS. I will rep you when I can.

Comment: It looks like the code is trying to determine if the $_POST'd $tid is valid or not (as in an int value greater than 0), so it can be tested later maybe? You don't need the (int) cast, since just after that you check if it's <= 0, which essentially eliminates floats. I'm not sure what you mean by the last sentence (setting $tid to false if $_POST['tid']?).

Answer (score 1):

A hidden HTML element would allow you to send form data between pages.

```
<form type=""...>
<input type="hidden" name"xx" value="yy" />
</form>
```

However, be careful relying on the values in hidden form elements, especially if the data is sensitive. Malicious users could alter the form data that gets posted, so you wouldn't want to put something that **shouldn't** be changed there (like a price).